# Bibliography as a table

Tags: bibtex

Is it possible to use bibtex (or maybe some other package) to produce the bibliography (from a bib file) in form of a table? For instance, having authors names in one column, titles in the other, and so on?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I must confess I've so far never seen a bibliography formatted in tabular form. If you know of an example, could you maybe provide a reference to it?

Comment: I don't know any example. But I guess this should be possible, am I wrong?

Comment: Surely using `biblatex` and choosing appropriate parts to cite, e.g., `\citeauthor`, and friends.